# Update duplicate rows for logical deletion in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, updates

I've seen a few other posts about deleting/updating duplicate rows, but I was a little confused about how to correctly apply it to my specific predicament.

Was hoping someone could give me a push in the right direction.

I have a table with some duplicate rows on it and would like to logically delete them for each user by setting the isdeleted column to 1.

My table has a primary key called Id that is an unsigned bigint, and it has a column called cid which represents another id that is duplicated. cid is not unique from user to user, but it should be unique for a specific user.

For example you could see this in my table:

```
id | cid | userid | is_deleted
1  | 1   | 100    | 0
2  | 2   | 101    | 0
3  | 1   | 102    | 0
4  | 1   | 100    | 0
5  | 2   | 101    | 0
```

So in this case, user#100 has two CIDs that are the same - on record #1 and record #4. Similarly, user#101 has two CID's that are the same - on record #2 and record #5

What I'd like to do is just take the duplicate CIDs for a given user and set is_deleted to 1, rather than purge the actual row.  I'd want to preserve one record as is_deleted = 0 so this way something is retained.

So an output I'd be hoping for is:

```
id | cid | userid | is_deleted
1  | 1   | 100    | 0
2  | 2   | 101    | 0
3  | 1   | 102    | 0
4  | 1   | 100    | 1
5  | 2   | 101    | 1
```

I can do this in code but it would be rather involved, and I've seen some amazing responses for pure SQL statements; would anyone be able to give some advice or offer a solution?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to update 1 row out of N repeated entries,

```
Update table t
inner join
(select id from table group by userid,cid having count(1)>1) t1
on t1.id = t.id
set t.is_deleted=1;
```